# How to cancel change in Bound Grid using Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: winforms, nhibernate, grid, fluent

I cannot figure out a pattern to use for working with a winform data grid that is bound to a set of data using fluent nhibernate.

I have a 'fluent' class called User, and am populating a data grid using the following:

> this.grid.DataSource =
>   session.CreateCriteria<User>().List<User>();

This works great, and I see my User record in my grid.  I can either use a transaction, or simply flush my session after making edits in the grid, and everything will persist correctly.  However, I can't figure out how to cancel the changes made to the User objects in the grid.  Even if I open the form within a session.BeginTransaction, when I call session.Transaction.RollBack(), the changes are not persisted to my database, but the session objects still have the changes, and are persisted next time the session is flushed.

I've look all over for best practices for Win Forms, and cannot find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, stop manually flushing the Session. If you need to manually flush the session, there is likely something seriously wrong with your design. Second of all, use transactions. Third of all, don't keep your session alive for long periods of time. Follow the [Unit of Work pattern](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the flushing was only for testing purposes.  Second of all, I am using transactions.  Third, I have been trying to have a session only live for the duration of the form that contains the datagrid.  I've read and have done a test implementation of the UoW pattern, but it still does not help me with my original question, which is:  What is a pattern/best practice that can be used to allow a data grid to be bound to a list of NHibernate entities, and to be able to cancel changes that were made in the grid.

Every single example or blog I've read about using fluent nhibernate in a Winforms environment has a pop up screen for editing individual records.  I need to allow users to edit entities in a grid.